# Generate 100 Java Tuple classes

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, code-generation

Write a script that writes to standard output, or your language's equivalent, 100 lines of (valid) Java code that begins with:

```
class Tuple1 {public Object _0;}
class Tuple2 {public Object _0,_1;}
class Tuple3 {public Object _0,_1,_2;}
class Tuple4 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3;}
class Tuple5 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4;}
class Tuple6 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5;}
class Tuple7 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6;}
class Tuple8 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7;}
class Tuple9 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8;}
class Tuple10 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9;}
class Tuple11 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10;}
class Tuple12 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11;}
```

The last line should begin with `class Tuple100`.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: I accept the challenge! In fact, I'm going to do this in Java!

Comment: Can I write a function or does it have to be a full program?

Comment: I'm new to the site so asked for a script, but I've been hearing it's customary to allow functions, and that makes a lot of sense for Java, to avoid `public static void main(String[] args)` so definitely give a function if you like.

Comment: Great! Thank you Ray!

Comment: It's not anywhere near small enough, but I think this a perfect place to share my `n`-tuple generator I wrote in Java: https://github.com/kenzierocks/Tuplocity. It generates fully generic tuples!

Comment: Unfortunately, this cannot be considered valid Java code, due to Java's (somewhat annoying) restriction that each class be declared in its own file.  Unless they're nested inner-classes, I suppose, but that severely limits the usefulness of this sort of construction...

Comment: The code in the question compiles fine for me. Java allows multiple top-level classes per file but only one _public_ top-level class. BTW, the generated Java code is not intended to be useful at all; it was taken from a tweet on a parody account. But the code _does_ compile---try it. :)

Comment: Be sure to edit the question to indicate that functions are allowed!

Comment: I can do this, but can you tell me what is customary here please? (1) A function producing a string that has newlines, (2) a function that writes to stdout as a side effect, or (3) both 1 and 2?

Comment: Output the same text or the same code? Is it ok to change spacing or adding comments inside of it?

Comment: That Java isn't perfectly golfed. You can remove the space after TupleX.

Comment: The Java code is not supposed to be golfed, The challenge was to write a golfed program to _generate the given code_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Jolf, 42 bytes

Do I get bonus points for beating Jelly with the best score ever? Contains unprintables, so you may want to try it [online here](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=wp_OnHp-MWQizp4vwojOryBUdXBsZSUge86eMMKMfyDOnjJRzrwgXyU7fSJIUnpIIixf). I replaced the unprintables with their respective alt index for readability.

```
‼Μz~1d"Ξ/êί Tuple% {Ξ0î⌂ Ξ2Qμ_ %;}"HRzH",_
```

### Explanation

```
‼Μz~1d"Ξ/êί Tuple% {Ξ0î⌂ Ξ2Qμ _%;}"HRzH",_
 Μz~1d                                     map the range 1..100 with the following function
      "                                    begin a string
       Ξ/êί                                short for "class"
            Tuple% {               H       string interpolate H (current number)
                    Ξ0î⌂ Ξ2Qμ              short for "public Object"
                              _%;}" RzH    string interpolate with a range from 1..H joined
                                       ",_  by the string ",_" (auto-closed quotes)
```

Comment: I suppose. Is it proper on this site to change the accepted answer if a new score comes in later?

Comment: @RayToal Yes, it is proper and even suggested to do so.

Comment: What's the character encoding for this?   I know golfing languages frequently use their own encoding, but I can't see which encoding jolf could be using.  I realize this is old.

Comment: @recursive The greek ISO-8859-7, this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7

Answer (score 24):

## vim <s>56</s> 54 keystrokes

```
iclass Tuple1 {public Object _0;}<esc>qyYp<C-a>$y2bPr,<C-a>q98@y
```

Since V is backwards compatible, you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/PzM5J7G4WCGktCAn1VChuqA0KSczWcE/KSs1uUQh3sC61ia1ONmusDKywMZZN9FOpdIoKaBIB8wutLRwqPz//79uGQA)

This is the perfect task for vim! I might golf it a little bit more later. Also note that `<c-a>` means Control-A, and it counts as one keystroke.

Explanation:

```
iclass Tuple1 {public Object _0;}<esc>         'Enter the starting text


qy                          'Start recording in register y
  Yp                        'Yank the current line, the print on the line below
     <C-a>                  'Increment the next digit to occur by one
          $                 'Move to the end of this line
           y2b              '(yank) 2 words (b)ack. This will grab '_0;'
              P             'Print the previously yanked word before the cursor.
               r,           '(r)eplace the char under the cursor with a comma.
                 <c-a>q     'Increment the current digit, then stop recording
                       99@y 'Playback macro 'y' 99 times.
```

Comment: If you count Control-A as one keystroke, you could substitute `yy` by `Y`.

Comment: @Seeq Haha, I just realized the same thing and edited it in right before I saw your comment. Great minds think alike!

Comment: This seems to be going to `class Tuple101`, not `class Tuple100` as the question asks.

Comment: @numbermaniac Simple off-by-one error. Thanks for pointing that out! Fixed now :)

Comment: @James your one line answer says `98@y` but your explanation still has `99@y` and talks about repeating `99 times.`

Answer (score 10):

## Jelly, 44 bytes

```
R’j“,_”
“¤>%,oỊȤʠ“ØụĊ5D³ṃṠɼQ»j;Ç;“;}¶”
ȷ2RÇ€
```

My first Jelly answer. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UuKAmWrigJwsX-KAnQrigJzCpD4lLG_hu4rIpMqg4oCcw5jhu6XEijVEwrPhuYPhuaDJvFHCu2o7w4c74oCcO33CtuKAnQrItzJSw4figqw&input=)

Comment: Am I doing it wrong or does this just output a giant list instead of a string?

Comment: @DenkerAffe It seems to be working now! There was a temporary bug in Jelly. (Also, the link was to an old version of my solution, so I've updated it.)

Comment: Nice... as of now it's 9 bytes shorter than the CJam solution!

Answer (score 9):

## Java, <strike>160</strike>, 125 Bytes

Thanks to @DenkerAffe,  @Denham Coote and  @Mathias Ettinger for the improvements.

Java writing java( because someone had to!)

```
void z(){String s="_0";for(int i=1;i<101;){System.out.println("class Tuple"+(i++)+" {public Object "+s+";}");s+=",_"+i;}}
```

#### And the un-golfed version

```
void z(){
    String s = "_0";
    for(int i = 1 ;i < 101;){
        System.out.println("class Tuple" + (i++) + " {public Object "+ s + ";}");
        s += ",_" + i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Unless stated otherwise in the challenge, you can alwasy use functions instead of full programs. So  you should use a Java8-lambda (which returns the result) here to save you all the `public static void main...`stuff.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. This answer includes an extra comma at the end of the Object declarations... `class Tuple1 {public Object _0,;}
class Tuple2 {public Object _0,_1,;}`

Comment: You can save a further 3 bytes by incrementing your loop counter in the sysout (++i) instead of (i+1) and removing `i++` from the for loop setup

Comment: You should start your `String s = "_0"` so you can `s += ",_" + i` and save a byte. It will also solve the problem with the trailing coma. You’ll need to start the for loop going from `1` to less than `101` and will be able to remove an extra 4 bytes by converting the `(i+1)` in your output message to only `i`. Obviously, you’ll need to print _before_ incrementing `s`.

Comment: Thanks, have done all these things, and am definitely going to have a gander at java8-lambda.

Comment: I know it's been more than 1.5 years, but it's currently giving incorrect results.. Your method goes from `_0,` to `_2,` instead of `_1`. You can fix this, and golf it by 5 bytes at the same time, like this: `void z(){String s="_0";for(int i=1;i<101;s+=",_"+i++)System.out.println("class Tuple"+i+" {public Object "+s+";}");}`. And you could golf it more with Java 8 using `()->` instead of `void z()` or better yet, `v->` instead (because [an empty unused parameter](https://tinyurl.com/yautfg47) is allowed). [Here is how to do this](https://tinyurl.com/yaj4hzlm) (resulting in **111 bytes**).

Answer (score 8):

### Pyth, <s>53</s> <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```
VS100%." }SüÆðQ´Ó3Ô«%&a´4UçõÛ"[Nj",_"UN
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VS100%25.%22+%7DS%C2%92%C3%BC%C3%86%C3%B0Q%C2%B4%C3%933%C3%94%10%C2%AB%25%07%C2%93%17%06%26%C2%89%19a%C2%B4%C2%9A4U%C3%A7%C3%B5%C3%9B%22%5BNj%22%2C_%22UN&debug=0)

Straightforward iteration over range(1,100) and building the corrosponding string from a packed string through formatting it.

### Explanation

```
VS100%." }SüÆðQ´Ó3Ô«%&a´4UçõÛ"[Nj",_"UN

VS100                                     # Iterate over range(1,100)
     %." }SüÆðQ´Ó3Ô«%&a´4UçõÛ"            # Unpack the string and format it
                              [           # List for formatting arguments
                               N          # Number of the Tuple
                                j    UN   # Join Object numbers...
                                 ",_"     # ...on the seperator ",_"
```

The unpacked string is `class Tuple%i {public Object _%s;}`

Comment: Two golfs: Use `s[` instead of all of those `+`. `[` makes an arbitrary length list, and `s` concatenates it. Also, since you want `[1, 2, ... 100]`, not `[0, 1, .. 99]`, use `VS100`, and you won't need either `h`.

Comment: @isaacg Thanks, did not know about the `S`-trick! :) Was already sitting on getting rid of all the `++++`, I knew there is a better way.

Comment: You;re welcome. By the way, you seem to have added a trailing `"` unnecessarily.

Comment: @isaacg Thanks for the hint. :) I removed it in my initial solution, but somehow it got back in when I edited in your suggestions :O

Comment: @isaacg Is there any reason `j<str><int>` doesn't `U`?

Comment: No, not really. Will do.

Answer (score 7):

## CoffeeScript, <s>86</s> 84 bytes

```
console.log "class Tuple#{i} {public Object _#{[0...i].join ',_'};}"for i in[1..100]
```

[View the solution online](https://jsfiddle.net/1500535g/)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Just to let you know [edits that improve answers are generally frowned](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/suggested-edits-reject-golfing/1619#1619) (and should be rejected if they end up in the review queue). So it's more likely that people will comment with suggestions, so you can review them yourself. :) (As for actual tips I think you need neither the space in front of `for` nor the one after `in`.)

Comment: Does `console.log"` work? (Don't know coffee script, that's a general trick.

Comment: No, as in, removing the space. :P I know it exists, I just don't know if that's valid syntax.

Comment: @VoteToClose I tried that earlier (using the live transpiler on coffeescript.org and it didn't work).

Comment: @VoteToClose Oh sorry didn't see that. No. somehow the space is required by the grammar, but it is not exactly clear to me why (yet). Spacing matters a lot in CoffeeScript, for instance, `x? y:z` is completely different from `x ? y:z`. You can say `console.log?"hello"` but not `console.log"hello"`. Significant whitespace. Sometimes nice, sometimes weird.

Comment: You can usually use functions for in- and output. So an anonymous lambda which implicitly returns the string might save you some bytes.

Comment: Oh-I didn't see that on either the site tour or the help center. So rather than requiring writing lines to stdout, is it customary to ask for a "function producing a string with newlines in it?" And if a function, can it not also be an expression generating the string without being the body of an anonymous function? Thanks for the patience and the tips; I'm looking to learn the customs here. If the custom is "stdout OR function OR expression" that's fine, but then should I edit the question accordingly?

Answer (score 6):

### Batch, 128 bytes

```
@set m=_0
@for /l %%t in (1,1,100)do @call:b %%t
@exit/b
:b
@echo class Tuple%1 {public Object %m%;}&set m=%m%,_%1
```

Edit: Saved 10 bytes thanks to @Bob. Saved 1 byte thanks to @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ.

Comment: I always get really happy to see batch on code golf, also, instead of using @ everywhere, you could redirect output to append to a file called x and use that as output

Comment: @DennisvanGils Sadly commands get echoed to standard output.

Comment: Eliminated `enabledelayedexpansion` for 117 bytes: https://gist.github.com/Elusive138/4cea555114a979954dcb -- if you don't mind the console window closing you can save two more by removing the `/b` arg from `exit`.

Comment: @Neil lol okay so I just tried running it and now I realize what you did. Very clever.

Comment: At beginning, use `@echo off`

Comment: @ElliotA. Why? That would waste 11 bytes.

Comment: Remove the other @'s, and `:b` doesn't print to the display.

Comment: @ElliotA. That still leaves me 6 bytes down...

Answer (score 6):

## Oracle SQL 9.2,  <del>138</del> 137 Bytes

```
SELECT REPLACE('class Tuple'||LEVEL||' {public Object'||SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(LEVEL-1,',_')||';}','t,','t ')FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<101;
```

@Peter Thanks for pointing the 0/1 mistake.

The query use the CONNECT BY CLAUSE of hierarchical query to generate 100 rows.

The LEVEL pseudocolumn contains the row number of each row.

SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH concatenate the first parameter, the row number, of each row, and use the second parameter as the separator.

Comment: please add some explanation

Comment: Clever :) This starts with `Object _1` instead of `Object _0`, so that will take another two bytes (`-1`). However, the `_` can be added to the char of `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` instead of concatenating, reducing it by two those bytes again: `REPLACE('class Tuple'||LEVEL||' {public Object'||SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(LEVEL-1,',_')||';}','t,_','t _')`

Answer (score 6):

### Powershell - 65 bytes

(Amended in response to comment)

All credit to TimmyD

```
1..100|%{"class Tuple$_ {public Object _$(0..($_-1)-Join",_");}"}
```

Comment: Why the vote down? (Please note this is my first ever post, not a great welcome?)

Answer (score 5):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina/), <s>80</s> 79 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
100$*1
1
class Tuple11$` {public Object 1$`}¶
1(?<= (1+))
_$1,
1(1)*
$#1
,}
;}
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=CjEwMCQqMQoxCmNsYXNzIFR1cGxlMTEkYCB7cHVibGljIE9iamVjdCAxJGB9wrYKMSg_PD0gKDErKSkKXyQxLAoxKDEpKgokIzEKLH0KO30&input=)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 65 bytes

```perl6
say "class Tuple$_ \{public Object _{join ',_',^$_};}" for 1..100
```

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 66 bytes

```apl
↑{∊'class Tuple'(⍕1+⍵)' {public Object _0'(',_'∘,∘⍕¨⍳⍵)';}'}¨0,⍳99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@jtonVjzq61JNzEouLFUJKC3JS1TUe9U411H7Uu1VTXaG6oDQpJzNZwT8pKzW5RCHeQF1DXSde/VHHDB0gBio8tOJR72awWuta9dpDKwx0gHxLS5Dp/9MA)

Explanation:

```apl
↑{∊'class Tuple'(⍕1+⍵)' {public Object _0'(',_'∘,∘⍕¨⍳⍵)';}'}¨0,⍳99
                                                             0,⍳99⍝ Numbers 0-99
                                                            ¨     ⍝ map to dfn
↑                                                                 ⍝ mix the result
  ∊'...'(⍕1+⍵)'...'                    ⍝ join the class header, tuple name (index + 1)
                                       ⍝ and the first tuple element.
                   (',_'∘,∘⍕¨⍳⍵)       ⍝ numbers from 1 to ⍵ prepended with ',_'
                                ';}'   ⍝ finish the class declaration
```

Comment: [Tradfn(-2)](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tP@P2qbWP2oo0s9OSexuFghpLQgJ1Vd41Hv1Ee9WzXVFaoLSpNyMpMV/JOyUpNLFOIN1DU01HXi1XUedS3SPLQCqA5EbAYrtq5VrwXzDA0M/wPN/p8GAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: [64](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@jtonVjzq61JNzEouLFUJKC3JS1TUe9U591LtVU12huqA0KSczWcE/KSs1uUQh3kBdQ10nXv1RxwwdIAYqO7TiUe9msFrrWvXaQysMdIB8S0uQ2f/TAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Calculuswhiz fair point, fixed.

Comment: use the right ⎕io and save a byte: `↑{∊⍕¨'class Tuple'⍵' {public Object '(1↓∊',_'∘,¨⍕¨⍳⍵)';}'}¨1+⍳100`

Comment: even shorter: `{∊⍕¨'class Tuple'⍺' {public Object '(1↓∊',_'∘,¨⍕¨⍳⍺)';}'}⌸1+⍳10`

Answer (score 4):

## R - <s>199</s> <s>132</s> <s>123</s> 118 bytes

Version 4

```
p=paste0;for(i in 1:10)cat(p("class Tuple",i," {public Object ",toString(sapply(0:(i-1),function(x)p("_",x))),";}\n"))
```

Version 3

```
p=paste0;for(i in 1:8)cat(p("class Tuple",i," {public Object ",p(sapply(0:(i-1),function(x)p("_",x)),collapse=","),";}\n"))
```

Version 2

```
p=paste0;for(i in 1:100)cat(p("class Tuple",i," {public Object ",p(sapply(0:(i-1),function(x)p("_",x)),collapse=","),";}"),sep="\n")
```

Version 1

```
for (i in 1:100){
  foo <- paste0("class Tuple", i, " {public Object ")
  for (j in 0:(i - 1)){
    foo <- if (j < (i - 1)) paste0(foo, "_", j, ",") else paste0(foo, "_", j, ";}")
  }
  print(foo)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Since this is a code golf competition, you'll want to make your code as short as possible. You could start by shortening variable names to a single character each, removing whitespace, and using `=` for assignment rather than `<-`.

Comment: 144 bytes: `for(i in 1:100){f=(p=paste0)("class Tuple",i," {public Object ");for(j in 0:(i-1))f=if(j<i-1)p(f,"_",j,",")else p(f,"_",j,";}");cat(f,sep="\n")}`

Comment: No problem. :) Also, you don't need to keep track of your versions in the post body since the revision history is accessible via the link that says "edited X minutes ago."

Comment: (though it may be worthwhile to give some indication, either in your edit summaries or in the post what you changed with each revision so that others could learn from your revision process)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 71 bytes

```ruby
100.times{|i|puts"class Tuple#{i+1} {public Object _#{[*0..i]*',_'};}"}
```

Comment: TIL `[*0..i]*',_'` wow

Answer (score 4):

## Java, 103 bytes

```
s->{s="_0";for(int i=0;i++<100;s+=",_"+i)System.out.printf("class Tuple%s {public Object %s;}\n",i,s);}
```

My first time here. Hi there! I went for a Java8 lambda expression (aka an anonymous function).

### Ungolfed version

```
s -> {
    s = "_0";
    for (int i = 0; i++ < 100; s += ",_" + i)
        System.out.printf("class Tuple%s {public Object %s;}\n", i, s);
}
```

To actually use this, as usual in Java8, you have to assign it to a variable of (or cast it to) an appropriate functional interface and then call its method; but technically, the function is only the lambda expression itself, so I am counting only that.

It also requires an input parameter, which saves me a couple bytes, since I can abuse it as a local variable without having to specify its type. I'm not sure if that's considered cheating, but to me it appears to be within the rules: I only saw people state that posting a function is allowed, not *how* that function needs to be invoked. :) And it doesn't actually read the parameter, so the function is still self-contained; you can pass any String to it, or even null, and it will still produce the correct output.

### And here is how to use it:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<?> r =
            s->{s="_0";for(int i=0;i++<100;s+=",_"+i)System.out.printf("class Tuple%s {public Object %s;}\n",i,s);}
        ;
        r.accept(null); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 96

```
def f(n=99):s=n and f(n-1)+',_'+`n`or"class Tuple%d {public Object _0";print s%-~n+';}';return s
```

## Python 3, 98

```
def f(n=99):s=n and f(n-1)+',_%d'%n or"class Tuple%d {public Object _0";print(s%-~n+';}');return s
```

**Usage:**

```
f()
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
def javatuple(n=99):
    if n == 0:
        s = "class Tuple%d {public Object _0"
    else:
        s = javatuple(n-1) + ',_' + str(n)
    print(s%(n+1) + ';}')
    return s
```

**formers:**

**103**

```
r=range
for i in r(100):
 print"class Tuple%d {public Object _%s;}"%(i+1,',_'.join(`j`for j in r(i+1)))
```

**108**

```
def f(n=99):
 if n:f(n-1)
 print"class Tuple%d {public Object _%s;}"%(n+1,',_'.join(`i`for i in range(n+1)))
```

Comment: In your python2 answer the last line seems to be incomplete :

`print f(3)`

gives :


`class Tuple1 {public Object _0;}`
`class Tuple2 {public Object _0,_1;}`
`class Tuple3 {public Object _0,_1,_2;}`
`class Tuple4 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3;}`
`class Tuple%d {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3`

Comment: @dieter The last line is a result. It's printed only when you run it interactively.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 63 bytes

```powershell
1..100|%{"class Tuple$_ {public Object _$(0..--$_-Join",_");}"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz9DAoEa1Wik5J7G4WCGktCAnVSVeobqgNCknM1nBPykrNblEIV5Fw0BPT1dXJV7XKz8zT0knXknTulap9v9/AA)

Two byte improvement of [bulletprooffool's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70915/78849), who seems to be an abandoned account now.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 53 bytes

```
100{)"class Tuple"\" {public Object _"1$,",_"*";}
"}/
```

[Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=100%7B)%22class%20Tuple%22%5C%22%20%7Bpublic%20Object%20_%221%24%2C%22%2C_%22*%22%3B%7D%0A%22%7D%2F).

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy, 74 chars

"join()" is unbeatable... New solution, thanks to @yariash

```groovy
100.times{println"class Tuple$it {public Object _${(0..it-1).join',_'};}"}
```

Old solution, 78 chars:

```groovy
(1..100).each{println"class Tuple$it {public Object _${(0..it-1).join',_'};}"}
```

Comment: You can use `100.times{}` instead of `(1..100).each{}`.

Comment: @yariash Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 43 bytes

```
тFNÝ„,_ý'_ì'Œº™'‚ÆN>'„à"ÿ Tupleÿ {ÿ ÿ ÿ;}"=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YpOb3@G5jxrm6cQf3qsef3iN@tFJh3Y9almk/qhh1uE2PzsgPe/wAqXD@xVCSgtyUoF0NRCDkXWtku3//wA)

Answer (score 2):

## FALSE, 85 bytes

```
1[$100>~][$$0"class Tuple"\." {public Object "[$@$@=~][\$0>[","]?$"_".1+]#";}
"%%1+]#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0vMKU79/98wWsXQwMCuLjZaRcVAKTknsbhYIaS0ICdVKUZPSaG6oDQpJzNZwT8pKzW5REEpWsVBxcEWqDhGxcAuWklHKdZeRSleSc9QO1ZZybqWS0lVFcT8/x8A)

Loops through 1-100 to get the Tuple number and then within that loops from 0 to currnum-1 to get underscores.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 36 bytes

```
`⟑↓ Tuɖ¾% {ƛḊ ß₂ %;}`₁ƛɾ\_$+\,j";v%⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJg4p+R4oaTIFR1yZbCviUge8ab4biKIMOf4oKCICU7fWDigoHGm8m+XFxfJCtcXCxqXCI7diXigYsiLCIiLCJbOSwgNywgLTEsIDYsIDUsIDIsIDExLCAxNiwgMjddIl0=)

```
     ₁ƛ         ;    # map 1...100 to...
       ɾ             # 1...n
        \_$+         # Prepend underscores to each
            \,j      # Join by commas
               "     # Pair with n
`...`                # Compressed string `class Tuple% {public object %;}`
                 v%  # Formatted with (n, names)
                   ⁋ # Join by newlines
```

Comment: This beat the accepted answer. Is it proper on this site to change the accepted answer when it gets beaten?

Comment: @RayToal Yes, or you can not accept any answer. Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, <s>128</s> 106 Bytes

I'm still trying to find a way to directly work on a printed value, and not on a string.

**Edit : Partially found it! I still need a string for the "_0,_1..." part, but it already is better :).**

```lua
s=""for i=0,99 do s=(s..",_"..i):gsub("^,",s)print(("class Tuple"..(i+1).." {public Object ")..s..";}")end
```

#### Old 128 Bytes solution

```lua
s="class Tuple1 {public Object _0;}"print(s)for i=1,99 do s=s:sub(1,s:find";"-1):gsub("e%d+","e"..i+1)..",_"..i..";}"print(s)end
```

#### Ungolfed

```lua
s=""
for i=0,99
do
  s=(s..",_"..i)              -- concatenate s with ",_i"
      :gsub("^,",s)           -- remove the leading "," for ",_0"
  -- then print the concatenated string
  print(("class Tuple"..(i+1).." {public Object ")..s..";}")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 96 Bytes

```
r=range
for i in r(1,101):print"class Tuple%d {public Object _%s;}"%(i,',_'.join(map(str,r(i))))
```

Thanks @DenkerAffe for the suggestion of using `lambda`.

Thanks @MathiasEttinger for the `join` idea.

Comment: You can golf this down to 111 bytes if you use a lambda in your reduce-call instead of defining a function for this: `reduce(lambda x,y:'%s,_%s'%(x,y), r(i))`

Comment: Or use `',_'.join(map(str,r(i)))` for an extra 14 bytes removal (or 15, since you left an extra space in your `reduce`).

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 77 bytes

```
for i=1:100;println("class Tuple$i {public Object _$(join(0:i-1,",_"));}")end
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <strike>111</strike> <strike>109</strike> 105 bytes

```
[print('class Tuple%s {public Object %s;}'%(i,','.join('_%i'%j for j in range(i))))for i in range(1,101)]
```

It's not the shortest thing in the world, I'm just participating.

edit1: down 2 bytes by removing `0,` in first `range`

edit2: I was unnecessarily casting `int` to `str` instead of just using `%i`... Down to 105.

Comment: Welcome, nice start! If interested, try `range(i)` in place of `range(0,i)` or since you used `range` twice, try `r=range` early then reference each call with just `r` (as in the other Python solutions).

Comment: Ugh, I forgot `range` starts at 0 by default. Down 2 bytes, however, adding `r=range;` in the beginning results in exactly the same character count, I've tried that! :D

Comment: Same comment than I did to [Dair](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70884/45032): `',_'.join(map(str,range(i)))` is 7 bytes shorter here.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 130 Bytes

```
{"class Tuple",ToString[#]," {public Object ",StringReplace[ToString[#-1&/@Range@#],{" "|"{" ->"_","}"->";}\n"}]}&/@Range[100]<>""
```

Comment: Hint: `\n` can be replaced with a literal newline character.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 85 Bytes

```
for(u<-1 to 100)println(s"class Tuple$u {public Object _${0 to u-1 mkString ",_"};}")
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 112 bytes

```php
<?php for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){$m.=$i==0?'_'.$i:',_'.$i;echo 'class Tuple'.($i+1).' {public Object '.$m.';}<br/>';}
```

Comment: You can save a few bytes by switching echo to double quotes where possible: `<?php for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){$m.=$i==0?"_$i":",_$i";echo 'class Tuple'.($i+1)." {public Object $m;}\n";}`

Comment: @Samsquanch Also, instead of `echo 'class Tuple'.($i+1)." {public Object $m;}\n";`, you can use `echo'class Tuple',$i+1," {public Object $m;}\n";`, which is 3 bytes shorter. Also, according to the meta, you can remove the `<?php` and assume that your code will be executed with `php -r "code"`. Also, you can do `for(;++$i<101;)echo"class Tuple$i {public Object ",$m=($m?"$m,":'')."_$i",";}\n";` for 80 bytes (you need to replace the `\n` with a real newline). Try it here: http://ideone.com/oOzKtP

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, <s>112</s> 110 bytes

2 bytes off thanks [@CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/c%E1%B4%8F%C9%B4%E1%B4%8F%CA%80-ob%CA%80%C9%AA%E1%B4%87%C9%B4).

```
_=>[...Array(100)].map((x,i)=>`class Tuple${++i} {public Object ${[...Array(i)].map((y,j)=>'_'+j)};}`).join`
`
```

Ungolfed:

```
_=>                                         // anonymous function
    [...Array(100)].map((x,i)=>             // 100 times [0..99]
        `class Tuple${++i} {public Object   // Tuple index + 1
            ${[...Array(i)].map(            // (index + 1) times
                (y,j)=>'_'+j                // _+j with j in [0..index]
            )}                              // Array without join prints comma in between
        ;}`                                 // as literal string
    ).join`\n`                              // display array line by line
```

Comment: I think you can replace `${i+1}` with `${i++}` and replace `${[...Array(i++)]` with `${[...Array(i)]`.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ. Thanks, I've updated with `++i`

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 116

<sup>(for the printing function only - according to some comments, this is in line with the rules)</sup>

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class T
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        T t = new T();
        t.p();
    }

    void p(){String s="_0";for(int i=0;i<100;){out.println("class Tuple"+ ++i+" {public Object "+ s + ";}");s+=",_"+i;}}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 55 bytes

```
2╤R`;r"$'_+"£M',j@k"c╙ò T╒α%d {pu▐V Object %s;}"⌡%`M'
j
```

Hexdump (reversible with `xxd -r`):

```
00000000: 32e2 95a4 5260 3b72 2224 275f 2b22 c2a3  2...R`;r"$'_+"..
00000010: 4d27 2c6a 406b 2263 e295 99c3 b220 54e2  M',j@k"c..... T.
00000020: 9592 ceb1 2564 207b 7075 e296 9056 204f  ....%d {pu...V O
00000030: 626a 6563 7420 2573 3b7d 22e2 8ca1 2560  bject %s;}"...%`
00000040: 4d27 0a6a                                M'.j
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=MuKVpFJgO3IiJCdfKyLCo00nLGpAayJj4pWZw7IgVOKVks6xJWQge3B14paQViBPYmplY3QgJXM7fSLijKElYE0nCmo&input=)

Yes, that newline is supposed to be there.

Explanation (newline replaced with `\n`):

```
2╤R`;r"$'_+"£M',j@k"c╙ò T╒α%d {pu▐V Object %s;}"⌡%`M'\nj
2╤R                                                       push range [1,100]
   `                                              `M      map:
    ;r                                                      push a, range(a)
      "$'_+"£M                                              map:
       $'_+                                                   stringify, prepend "_"
              ',j                                           join with commas
                 @k                                         swap and push stack as list
                   "c╙ò T╒α%d {pu▐V Object %s;}"⌡           decompress, result is
                                                              "class Tuple%d {public Object %s;}"
                                                 %          string format
                                                    '\nj  join with newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 52 bytes

```
Lo £`cÓ? TÕà{X} \{puÞV Object {Xò ®'_+Z}&}` r&59d} ·
```

The `?` should be the literal byte 0x95. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=TG8go2Bj05UgVNXge1h9IFx7cHXeViBPYmplY3Qge1jyIK4nXytafSZ9YCByJjU5ZH0gtw==&input=)

Japt has:

- **concise syntax** to help shorten your code.
- **string compression** to help shorten it even further.
- **lots of bugs** to make you want to throw your computer out the window.

I can't even use a semicolon in the string because the function it's wrapped in wants to return everything after the semicolon. This should only be 46 bytes:

```
Lo £`cÓ? TÕà{X} \{puÞV Object {Xò ®'_+Z};}`} ·
```

But alas, it is not. I'll see if I can fix these bugs over the next couple of hours.

#### How it works

```
Lo £       }  // Generate the range [0..100), and map each item X in this range to:
`cÓ? TÕà{X}   //  "class Tuple" + X +
\{puÞV Object //  "{public Object" +
{Xò ®'_+Z}    //   Create the range [0..X] and map each item Z to "_" + Z.
              //   Upon stringification, this automatically inserts the commas.
&}`           //  + "&}"
r&59d         //  Replace the "&" with String.fromCharCode(59), or ";".
·             // Join the result with newlines.
```

Comment: Bah! Ninjaed by ~18 months! You need to increment the first `X`, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 97 bytes

```
(1..100).each{println "class Tuple${it} {public Object ${(0..it-1).collect{"_$it"}.join(',')};}"}
```

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/oOFUlJ)

Comment: You can user 100.times{} instead of (1..100).each{}, which saves 4 bytes.

Comment: You can also omit braces in join (`join','`), remove space after println, and replace `.collect{}` with `*.with{}`

Answer (score 1):

## C++, <del>164</del> <del>159</del> 157 bytes (155 as function only)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define o std::cout<<
int main(){int j,i=0;for(;i<100;++i){o"class Tuple"<<i+1<<" {public Object _0";for(j=0;++j<=i;)o",_"<<j;o";}\n";}}
```

This is a full program. You can save 2 bytes in function only form if you replace `int main()` with `void f()`.

[Run code in Ideone](http://ideone.com/miCH2z)

### Ungolfed, including macro expansion

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int j,i=0;
    for(;i<100;++i)
    {
        std::cout << "class Tuple"<< i+1 <<" {public Object _0";
        for(j=0;++j<=i;)
            std::cout << ",_" << j;
        std::cout << ";}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Nice first answer! Unless stated otherwise in the challenge, you can always use functions instead of full programs, so you can save a few bytes by doing that. You still have to include iostream tho, since its needed for the output.

Comment: You might also want to do `j=1` in your for loop, thus not having the `if(j)`.

Comment: @Ethiraric But of course! How sloppy of me. I guess I got too focused on the idea "remember to skip additions on first line" and ended up writing that too literally.

Comment: @sendaran Or even may be `for(int j=0;++j<=i;)` would save one more byte.

Comment: @Ethiraric Did that and shaved off an extra byte by extracting variable declarations, which enabled another empty expression.

Answer (score 1):

## , 44 chars / 55 bytes

```
⩥ṥⓜᵖ`э£ēÕ>rĕĠ#⦃$⦄ {public Object ⦃⩤$ⓜ⍘_+$⦄;}
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=false&input=&code=%E2%A9%A5%E1%B9%A5%E2%93%9C%E1%B5%96%60%D1%8D%C2%A3%C4%93%C3%95%3Er%C4%95%C4%A0%23%E2%A6%83%24%E2%A6%84%20%7Bpublic%20Object%20%E2%A6%83%E2%A9%A4%24%E2%93%9C%E2%8D%98_%2B%24%E2%A6%84%3B%7D)</kbd>

Still amazing even without compression.

## Explanation

```
⩥ṥⓜᵖ`э£ēÕ>rĕĠ#⦃$⦄ {public Object ⦃⩤$ⓜ⍘_+$⦄;} // implicit: ṥ=input
⩥ṥⓜ                                          // generate [0,100) to map over
    ᵖ                                         // push to stack:
     `э£ēÕ>rĕĠ#⦃$⦄                             // class Tuple[insert mapitem here]
                  {public Object ⦃⩤$ⓜ⍘_+$⦄;} // {public Object [insert [0,mapitem] here preceded by semicolons per item];}
                                             // implicit stack output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```
LhP["class Tuple"++i" {public Object "'_.,iJ',";}"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fJyMgWik5J7G4WCGktCAnVUlbO1NJobqgNCknM1nBPykrNblEQUk9Xk8n00tdR8m6Vin2/38A)

Explanation:

```
                        h is preinitialized to 100 and i to 0 (implicit)
L h                     Loop 100 times:
 P [                    Print the following list (with trailing newline):
    "class Tuple"
    ++i                 Increment i here so that its values run from 1 to 100
    " {public Object "
    ('_ . ,i) J ',      Range(i), concatenate "_" before each element, join on ","
    ";}"
   ]                    By default, lists are concatenated when printed
```

Comment: Idea: Maybe name your language so that it doesn't get confused with the [`pip`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29) utility

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Yeah, I realized that problem after the fact... but I think now it is what it is.  (When I came up with the acronym "Pip Isn't Python," it seemed so perfect...)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 85 bytes

```
s='_0';for(i=1;i<101;s+=',_'+i++)console.log(`class Tuple${i} {public Object ${s};}`)
```

Comment: Very nice! Could you add an explanation? Also, I believe you could save a single byte by moving `s+=',_'+i++` into the last bit of the `for`.

Comment: Thanks! The for loop prints out each line whilst adding to the _0,_1,_2... string (stored in s) at the end of each iteration. Uses ES6 template strings to save a few bytes :P

Comment: (I meant [edit] an explanation into your question. Answers with them tend to be better-received)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 107 bytes

```
time {set s "class Tuple[incr i] \{public Object \{"
set j 0
time {set s $s\_$j\;
incr j} $i
puts $s\}} 100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYuxDoQgEAV7vuLF8AFY@xE21x3G6IZiCXch7lIZvh2VynIyM0qpNeVfwClBIRgobSL4lJzCl/90gBf4M5c9MWHeYyC9eTBPHuHMe7biVxv9ZPoYKyybXLSLWjE619oF)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 117 bytes

```
proc P n {set i 0;time {append s _$i\;;incr i} $n;set s}
time {puts "class Tuple[incr i] {public Object [P $i]}"} 100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcoxDoMwDAXQvaf4QjlAOucQZWCjqALXg1GaWthMKGcPQszvOeXWdPsTehQcxg5BTC4/xjGrcvnC8AnyTkkKbZCKUNL1rD7uprsbOsqzGYZdM4/3nC5ashBey8rkGHsEmWpX8YyxtRM)

Comment: Got the same **107 bytes** count with: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaG6OLVEoVhBKTknsbhYIaS0ICc1OjMvuUghM1YhprqgNCknM1nBPykrNbkEyFfiAinPUtA15ELWrVIcEw/RlRUbY12roJLJVVBaAhavrVUwNDD4/x8A

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 97 bytes

```forth
: f 101 1 do cr ." class Tuple"i 1 .r ." {public Object _0"i 1 ?do ." ,_"i 1 .r loop ." ;}"loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRgaGCoYKqTkKyQXKegpKSTnJBYXK4SUFuSkKmUCJfTAotUFpUk5mckK/klZqcklCvEGYDl7oC6gpE48TGVOfn4BSMS6VgnMtP6f9h8A)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                           \ start a new word definition
  101 1 do                    \ start a loop from 1 to 100
    cr                        \ output a new line
    ." class Tuple"i 1 .r     \ output "class TupleN" where N is the loop index
    ." {public Object _0"     \ output "{public Object _0"
    i 1 ?do                   \ start a loop from 1 to the outer loop index
      ." ,_"i 1 .r            \ output ",_N" where N is the inner loop index
    loop                      \ end the inner loop
    ," ;}"                    \ output ";}"
  loop                        \ end the outer loop
 ;                            \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 93 bytes

```python
i=1;exec'print"class Tuple%s {public Object _"%i+",_".join(map(str,range(i)))+";}";i+=1;'*100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxRCoQgEADQq8hApGtE9St7hn72X0yG3QmzQQ02Ys/u9g7w@CyfPU610nM0@EXfcqJYwAeXs3gdHLDJ4uJjCeTFvKzoi7DQkIbOQr/uFOXmWOaSuuTiGyUppTSYHxjS99k@xmGo9Q8)

I rarely get to use `exec` in code golf, so I wasn't going to pass on this one!

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 67 bytes

```
{1@,/("class Tuple";$x;" {public Object _";",_"/$!x;";}\n")}'1+!100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/7/a0EFHX0MpOSexuFghpLQgJ1XJWqXCWkmhuqA0KSczWcE/KSs1uUQhXslaSSdeSV9FEShpXRuTp6RZq26orWhoYPD/PwA)

A bunch of string concatenations, with `",_"/$!x` probably being the most interesting part.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 82 bytes

```python
s="class Tuple%d {public Object _0"
i=1
exec"print s%i+';}';s+=',_%d'%i;i+=1;"*100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAe69YBBGyg3YV39Cle5QKbYhJq1BEb7eZ/JT9TGNrZJmLKxHMNcfAPby5bhEdTNsRXIFFsQ6t7sIdHMsXpgLEUQrzCUPSimHhXnA0KK02rNdKtfYD)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 69 bytes

```perl
$p='{public Object _0';say("class Tuple$_ $p;}"),$p.=",_$_"for 1..100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExCoAwDADAr4QSUEFLOjiJTxAX96KlglJssHUQ8evGO/ZnaEWQ@@Lhawmbg3HZvctgqejSfJfKhTklmC4OHi0gd6@qamTdq9qiVWs8wWhtiES@yHmLR5JmaDUZ@gE)

Comment: Shouldn't the semicolon come before the curly bracket?

Comment: @RezNesX: Yes, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 66 bytes

```
(class Tuple(${$2+1}!1) \{public Object ($3,_${$2-1}!_0);\}
){100}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdcGCpaUlaboWN500knMSi4sVQkoLclI1VKpVjLQNaxUNNRViqgtKk3IykxX8k7JSk0sUNFSMdeJB8rpA-XgDTeuYWi7NakMDg1qISVADYQYDAA)

#### Explanation

```
(class Tuple(...) \{public Object (...);\}\n){100}
```

Repeat this text 100 times, with the ellipses being as follows:

```
(${$2+1}!1)
```

This is capture group 2. Try to increment the value from the last time group 2 matched. If this is the first iteration, there isn't a previous match for group 2; in that case, use `1` instead.

```
($3,_${$2-1}!_0)
```

This is capture group 3. Try to match the same string group 3 matched last time, followed by `,_`, followed by one less than the value we just matched for group 2. If this is the first iteration, there isn't a previous match for group 3; in that case, use `_0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl5, 77 Bytes

```
$"=", ";for(0..100){push@o,"_$_";print"class Tuple$_\{public Object @o;\}\n"}
```

Also

```
for(0..100){$o.=$o?", _$_":"_$_";print"class Tuple$_\{public Object $o;\}\n"}
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! Please put your language together with the byte count in the title and format the code correctly (see my edit). Hope your have a great time here! :)

Comment: You don't have to put a backslash for the first accolade in the print : `print"class Tuple$_{public Object $o;\}\n"}`

Comment: You have an off-by-one error, the first line should be `Tuple1 … _0;`. The simple fix would be to put the `push` after the `print` and to make the `print` conditional on `$_`. `…;for(0..100){$_&&print …;push@o,"_$_"}`

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 59 bytes

```
100:"'class Tuple%i {public Object %s}'@'_%i,'@:qYD59O(3$YD
```

*EDITS*

- *(May 16, 2016): to adapt to recent changes in the language, `O` needs to be replaced by `J` in the above code.*
- *(September 29, 2017): the order of the inputs to `YD` has changed, which requires some modifications in the code.*

*The following link includes these changes*.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39DAwErJwcGqUD1eNVNHPdLF1NJLQz05J7G4WCGktCAnVTVTobqgNCknM1nBPykrNblEQbW4Vt1YJdLl/38A)

Answer (score 0):

### Java 1.8, 163 Bytes

```java
interface T{static void main(String[]a){String o="";for(int i=0;i<100;){o+=(i>0?",":"")+"_"+i;System.out.println("class Tuple"+(++i)+" {public Object "+o+";}");}}}
```

#### Ungolfed

```java
interface T{
static void main(String[]a){
    String o="";
    for(int i=0;i<100;){
        o+=(i>0?",":"")+"_"+i;
        System.out.println("class Tuple"+(++i)+" {public Object "+o+";}");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Unless stated otherwise in the challenge, you can always use functions instead of full prorgams. So youcan save all that `static void main...` stuff by using a Java8-lambda which implictly returns the result.

Comment: Old habits die hard ;)

Answer (score 0):

### AWK, 84 Bytes

`BEGIN{m=" {public Object _0";for(i=1;i<101;){print"class Tuple"i m";}";m=m",_"i++}}`

I do like playing with AWK.

If the script were placed in a file, `tuple.awk`, and called with a 1 line input, the `BEGIN` tag could be removed... e.g.
`echo 1|awk -f tuple.awk`

Not sure if any other golfing could be done to it.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 103 chars

```
(map(fn[n](prn(str"class Tuple"n" {public Object "(join","(map #(+"_"%)(range n)))";}")))(range 1 101))
```

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 80 characters

(78 characters code + 2 characters command line option.)

```
range(1;13)|"class Tuple\(.) {public Object \([range(.)|"_\(.)"]|join(","));}"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ bin/jq -nr 'range(1;101)|"class Tuple\(.) {public Object \([range(.)|"_\(.)"]|join(","));}"' | head
class Tuple1 {public Object _0;}
class Tuple2 {public Object _0,_1;}
class Tuple3 {public Object _0,_1,_2;}
class Tuple4 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3;}
class Tuple5 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4;}
class Tuple6 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5;}
class Tuple7 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6;}
class Tuple8 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7;}
class Tuple9 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8;}
class Tuple10 {public Object _0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9;}
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=range%281%3B13%29|%22class%20Tuple%5C%28.%29%20%7Bpublic%20Object%20%5C%28[range%28.%29|%22_%5C%28.%29%22]|join%28%22,%22%29%29%3B%7D%22&j=null) (Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 106 bytes

`(let(y)(dotimes(x 100)(push x y)(format t"class Tuple~d {public Object ~{_~d~^,~};}~&"(1+ x)(reverse y))))`

[Try it online!](http://ideone.com/VFFRsa)

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 166 Bytes

```
void m(){int c=0;while(c!=100){System.out.print("class Tuple"+(c+1)+" {public Object ");for(int i=0;i<c+1;i++)System.out.print(",_"+i);System.out.print(";}\n");c++;}}
```

Not bad for java, I mean calling main() alone is like 10+ bytes.. (plus long print statements)

### (Non-Competetive) Java w/ [Quick-Print!](https://github.com/niwhsa9/Quick-Print) 137 bytes

```
import t.Q;
void m(){int c=0;while(c!=100){Q.p("class Tuple"+(c+1)+" {public Object ");for(int i=0;i<c+1;i++)Q.p(",_"+i);Q.p(";}\n");c++;}}
```

This one uses a quick library I have been thinking about making for a while(and just made) for shortening the long java print statements. It saves 29 bytes and that was just with 3 system.out.print() calls in the original. I've marked this one as non-competetive since the lib was made after the challenge was posted. Also, I don't know if we are allowed to use cheap little tricks like this and I felt bad about it. (Although in a way its fair since java has the longest print statements of any language I know).

Answer (score 0):

### Java 8, <s>184</s> 194 bytes

(just to add `void r()` as mentioned in the comments)

```
void r(){IntStream.rangeClosed(1,100).mapToObj(i->IntStream.range(0,i).mapToObj(j->"_"+j).collect(Collectors.joining(",","class Tuple"+i+" {public Object ",";}"))).forEach(System.out::println);}
```

Ungolfed

```
void r(){ IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
    .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, i).mapToObj(j -> "_" + j)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "class Tuple" + i + " {public Object ", ";}")))
    .forEach(System.out::println); }
```

Comment: This code isn't even in a function or anything... You need to add like void r(){ around it }

Comment: Np. Why is your "," seperate from your "\_" if the are right next to each other when you print? You may be able to cut some bytes by using this string: ",_"

Comment: @AshwinGupta `","` is used as a delimiter for a `Stream<String>` of `_0 _1 _2...`. If I'm going to used `",_"` as the delimiter, the `mapToObj()` conversion is longer (`String::valueOf`), and I'll need an additional `_` at the end of `" {public Object "` to handle that.

Comment: oh okay I didn't know that. I'm a begginer programmer really. I just noticed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 99 bytes

```
0:99eI+1=J,[J]:"class Tuple~w {public Object "w,(I{:0reI,(?I,F";";?'I,F","):"w~_"cr:[I]rw\};"}
"w\)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 119 bytes

I'm new to Scala and to codegolf, so nothing fancy.

```
for(i<-1 to 100){print("class Tuple"+i+" {public Object "); for(j<-0 to i-2) print("_"+j+","); print("_"+(i-1)+";}\n")}
```

[Try online](https://ideone.com/JxoyEB)

More readable version:

```
for (i <- 1 to 100) {
  print("class Tuple" + i + " {public Object ")
  for (j <- 0 to i - 2) print("_" + j + ",")
  print("_" + (i - 1) + ";}\n")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 131 bytes

Call `j`.

```hs
import Data.List
j=mapM_(\n->putStrLn("class Tuple"++show n++" {public Object _"++intercalate",_"(map show[0..n-1])++";}"))[1..100]
```

Answer (score 0):

## BlitzMax, 81  bytes

```
While i<100s$:+",_"+i i:+1Print"class Tuple"+i+" {public Object "+s[1..]+";}"Wend
```

That's the whole program.
Non-Strict and without a Framework, so I can use variables without declaration and Print without having to import StandardIO. The String slicing operator comes in handy here, since it allows me to easily remove the superfluous comma at the beginning of each Object list.

### Ungolfed version

```
While i < 100
    s$ :+ ",_" + i
    i :+ 1
    Print "class Tuple" + i + " {public Object " + s[1..] + ";}"
Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 96 bytes

```
r=range
for i in r(1,101):print('class Tuple%d {public Object _0'%i,*r(1,i),sep=',_',end=';}\n')
```

Joining its expanded positional arguments from `*range(1,i)` using a custom separator `,_` and ending each line with `;}`, Python 3's `print()` function happily does the job almost entirely on its own.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6, <s>128</s> 122 chars

```
for(s="class Tuple1 {public Object _0;}",q=0;q++<100;s=s.replace(/\d+(?!\d|,)( )?/g,(m,s)=>[q+1+s][+s]||m+",_"+q))alert(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin, 92 Bytes

```
fun j(){var s="_0";for(i in 1..100){println("class Tuple$i {public Object $s;}");s+=",_"+i}}
```

[Try it online!](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/2fugfbni64lkctlklt6vq4o55p/1u8lgc6n6tge3luu4f7h6j4cls)

#### Ungolfed

```
fun j(){
    var s = "_0"
    for(i in 1..100){
        println("class Tuple$i {public Object $s;}")
        s+=",_"+i
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>68</s> 66 bytes

```perl
$"=',_';say"class Tuple$_ {public Object _@{[0..$_++]};}"for 0..99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FyVZdJ17dujixUik5J7G4WCGktCAnVSVeobqgNCknM1nBPykrNblEId6hOtpAT08lXls7tta6Viktv0gByLe0/P//X35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 47 bytes

```
iclass Tuple1 {public Object _0;}99ñÙ$hi,_Û
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/PzM5J7G4WCGktCAn1VChuqA0KSczWcE/KSs1uUQh3sC6VtrS8vDGwzMZVTIydeIPz5aW@P8fAA)

Answer (score 0):

### C++, <s>139</s> 137 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<iostream>
auto&p=printf;void j(){int i=1,k;for(;i<101;++i){p("class T%d{",i);for(k=0;k<i;++k)p("public Object v%d;",k);p("}");}}
```

Comment: Woah, nice golf! If you're straying from the source to generate equivalent valid java code (using `public Object v0;public Object v1;` instead of `public Object _0,_1;`, removing the space before `{`) then can't you change `p("}\n")` to `p("}")`? That raises another question, are you allowed to stray from the source?

Comment: @Zacharý actually, the code outputed is `class T2{public Object v0;public Object v1}`, so... I may try to use some printf magic to erase a full loop

Comment: Secondly, why are using <iostream> instead of <cstdio> if you're just using printf? Unless I'm missing something, that may work.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>110</s> 109 bytes

```cs
int i;for(;i++<100;)Write($"class Tuple{i} {{public Object _{string.Join(",_",Enumerable.Range(0,i))};}}\n");
```

Saved a byte thanks to @dana

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcG9CsMgEADgVzmkgxIb7GzXLl0CpdClEFSu4Yq9BH8m8dnt94V8DpnGIC5A9rMnaWmarhdjrHolKihPIkSXMzzrEbFRh9aO6iMFWPwXQ4G15ZKIt/m@E0uhV6FvXH@YnI84PxxvKI0mpbrt/c1C2TH@)

Comment: [109](https://tio.run/##BcG9CsMgEADgVzmkgxIb7GzXLl0CpdClEFSu4Yq9BH8m8dnt94V8DpnGIC5A9rMnaWmarhdjrHolKihPIkSXMzzrEbFRh9aO6iMFWPwXQ4G15ZKIt/m@E0uhV6FvXH@YnI84PxxvKI0mpbrt/c1C2TH@ "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online") - declare `i` at the top level ;)

Answer (score 0):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 87 bytes

```
-(i)class Tuple{i} \{public Object <>
~temp k=-1
-(j)~k++
_{k}{k<i:,->j};\}
{i<100:->i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExCoAwDADAva/IqGhAV639goujIFo6pKlSUKcQv17v6OJSsKLap/2@YXlzCkIKq@T3SORhPmLwD1hnviecGXjC3mAV64@bxmzCKmxpaNFFHVc1QrbvugEdaSk/)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>118</s> <s>116</s> 114 bytes

```c
i,j,(*p)()=printf;main(){for(;j=i++<100&&p("class Tuple%d {public Object _0",i);p(";}\n"))for(;j<i;)p(",_%d",j++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzLCoMwEAB/JQSU3SaF9Lz6Db30WBCNWjakcfFxEr89DfQ6zIy/@9inT85s4SYI2MrKaZ/p23OCgOe8rEChZWOah3N1LaBLsW3qdUicqlGdcgyRvXoOYfK76py2jFQ0ut5JI/4HDRMWZrtq1DYYg3Tl/AM)

### Explanation

Note that I put a few statements into the for loop header, but the logic is the same.

**Only works with clang.** GCC errors on `(*p)()=printf`.

Ungolfed version:

```c
// Define our loop counters....
int i, j;
// And our function pointer to printf (saves 4 bytes)
// Clang is generous enough to accept this monstrosity.
//
// Remember that f() in C represents an unspecified number of arguments,
// unlike C++. 
// This is why you should always compile with -Wstrict-prototypes. :)
int (*p)() = printf;

int main()
{
    // Static and globals default to 0, so we don't need i=0.
    // Loop from 1 to 100.
    while (i++ < 100) {
        // Print the beginning of the string with printf.
        // For ease, of implementation, we print the initial _0 so we can
        // just print ",_j" later.
        p("class Tuple%d {public Object _0", i);
        // Print all the members starting at _1.
        // Loop j for 1 to i - 1. We skip the first iteration.
        for (j = 1; j < i;)
            // Print ",_j"
            p(",_%d", j++);
        // Print the end of the class declaration.
        p(";}\n");
    }
}
```

Thanks to ceilingcat for the -2 bytes by using the first for loop condition to set `j`!

Answer (score 0):

### Google Sheets, 142

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `=SEQUENCE(1,100` - Named Range `A` |
| 2 | `;}` - Named Range `B` |
| 3 | `=ArrayFormula("class Tuple"&A&" {public Object "&SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(FLATTEN(A)>=A,"_"&A-1,)),",,+",B),B)&B` |

+1 for each named range.

#### Fun facts

`Flatten` is an undocumented function. Takes any matrix and makes it into a column vector. This includes row vectors too, so I used it instead of `Transpose`.

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>881</s> 781 bytes

```
--->-[<++>-----]>+[[-]--[----->+<]>---.+++++++++.-----------.--[---<+>]<--..+[---->+<]>+++.----[-<+++>]<.-[--->+<]>++++.-----.----.-------.[-]<<+[>>->+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<[[+]<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<[[-]+>--[<+>++++++]<.>-[<+>-----]<.[-]<[-]<[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]]<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>>+[[-]<[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[->[-]>>+>+<<<]]]]]]]]]<]>>[>]-[<+>-----]<--->>>]<<<[.[-]<<<]<<[>>+>-<<<-]>>+[<<+>>-]+>[<->[+]]<[+++[->++++++++<]>.>--[-->+++++<]>.[-<+++>]<-.+++++.+[->+++<]>.++++++++++.---.------.[-------<+++>]<<.>.-[----->+++<]>.++++++++.-----.--.-[---<+>]<--.<.>+[->+++<]>.+[--<+>]<.[-]<[-]<]<[-]<[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]<<<[>>->+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<]+[--------->+<]>++.-[---<++>]<+.>++++++++++.[-]<[-]<[-]<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>>-[<<<+>>>-]<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJRasRACD2Q6AnEi4gf3YVCKfSjsOdPn85oE7oLFZLJ5OnTp96@3z6@3h/3z@NgZmNXIuO0MHLnYPa6GmkkINQm/Guy3JQsFDchn5j2dKCUuJRrY5tG5pUn8qqSm6WbKmoxc3wQTkDuBBwwPYVfIyko5UGlLREop0RvzVqp61kUyeAVzxFX4v5tq1EZofzvF5tXaNFFmyavxbmi7JWhbZC1@qKtkHch1JUQagIvZaXQhhw9K/CK1Yxs7jOQPVPZAYnRZcoyY1m249A6me24xs1Q5bIXiDgn8Y1M01@2Xkvy820I8tnDvVWdNclJ7KRmxvt3T/jMeRw/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 53 bytes

```
FNS*TTs["class Tuple"N" {public Object "j\,m+\_dUN";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/380vWCskpDhaKTknsbhYIaS0ICdVyU9JobqgNCknM1nBPykrNblEQSkrRidXOyY@JdRPybr2/38A)

---

```
Pyth                                                   | Python 3
-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------
FNS*TTs["class Tuple"N" {public Object "j\,m+\_dUN";}  | 
FNS*TTs["class Tuple"N" {public Object "j\,m+\_dUN";}" | 
-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------
FNS*TT                                                 | for N in range(1, 101):
                                                       |     print(
      s[                                               |       "".join([
        "class Tuple"                                  |         "class Tuple",
                     N                                 |         str(N),
                      " {public Object "               |         " {public Object ",
                                        j\,            |         ",".join(
                                           m           |           map(
                                            +\_d       |             lambda d: "_" + str(d),
                                                UN     |             range(N)
                                                       |           )
                                                       |         ),
                                                  ";}" |         ";}"]
                                                       |       )
                                                       |     )
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 65 bytes

```bash
for i ({1..100})<<<"class Tuple$i {public Object _0$s;}"&&s+=,_$i
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY3HdPyixQyFTSqDfX0DA0MajVtbGyUknMSi4sVQkoLclJVMhWqC0qTcjKTFfyTslKTSxTiDVSKrWuV1NSKtW114lUyIQZBzYOZCwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 173 bytes

```go
import(."strings";."fmt")
func f(){for i:=1;i<101;i++{s:=[]string{}
for j:=0;j<i;j++{s=append(s,Sprint("_",j))}
Printf("class Tuple%d {public Object %s;}\n",i,Join(s,","))}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY9BasMwEEX3OoUYCEhEDcmuWPEFumkg2aWhKIplRrVlYckr4ZN0YwrdpcseprepXHczw_D_H95__6i76e6VflN1RVuF7nOI5uHx5wtb3_WRbSDEHl0dQG7AtBE4MYPT1DCeTNdTLMqdxP1um-d6nUJRni9LIo1kNtii3Eq7R2lnuVTeV-7Ggjj6bIoMXkFYzkdymE_DQDcqBHoafFOtbjT54dqgps9XW-lIV0GOLw4EiqcOXf4CAnJ4XKC__8jmEozTREhmJORfm6Zl_wI)

Prints to STDOUT.

## [Go 1.22+](https://go.dev), 173 bytes

```go
import(."strings";."fmt")
func f(){for i:=range 100{s:=[]string{}
for j:=range i+1{s=append(s,Sprint("_",j))}
Printf("class Tuple%d {public Object %s;}\n",i+1,Join(s,","))}}
```

[Run this on the Go Playground!](https://go.dev/play/p/mU_wBOMjmNv?v=gotip)

Alternate solution using the new integer-range loops coming in Go 1.22.

Answer (score -1):

**Java 112 bytes**

> ```
> void p(){String x="_0";for(int i=0;i<100;){out.format("class Tuple %d {public Object %s;}\n",++i,x);x+=",_"+i;}}
> ```

Un-golfed

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class I {
public static void main(String[] args){
    I m=new I();
    m.p();
}
    void p(){
    String x="_0";
    for(int i=0;i<100;){
        out.format("class Tuple %d {public Object %s;}\n", ++i, x);
        x+=",_"+i;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to import `System` or use `System.out`.

Answer (score -1):

## Haskell, 102 bytes

```
putStr$[0..99]>>= \a->"class Tuple"++show(a+1)++" {public Object _0"++([1..a]>>=(",_"++).show)++";}\n"
```

### As a program (107 bytes):

```
main=putStr$[0..99]>>= \a->"class Tuple"++show(a+1)++" {public Object _0"++([1..a]>>=(",_"++).show)++";}\n"
```

### Explanation

```
putStr$ -- print it all
  [0..99]>>= \a->                 -- For each a from 0 to 99, make the
                                  -- following string, then concat
                                  -- it all together

    "class Tuple" ++ show (a + 1) -- class name (starts at Tuple1)

    ++" {public Object _0"        -- All Tuple classes start with a _0

    ++([1..a]>>=(",_"++).show)    -- If we're on TupleA,
                                  -- concat together ",_1", ",_2", etc.
                                  -- up to "_A"

    ++";}\n"
```